# Under what condition can we import protected pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, includegraphics

I was able to integrate pdf (with includegraphics) which were only protected against modification. To my amazement, I was then able to edit and modify the pdf (with Acrobat). What becomes of the protections.
On the other hand, I was not able to integrate a document which was protected by a password when opening. How to pass the password via includepdf or includegraphics?

What are the possibilities and limits of the integration of a protected pdf in latex.

Comment: PDF permissions can be modified by anybody, if no password is set. If you have a password protected PDF and know the password, you could remove the protection before including it. Afterwards, you can change the permissions of the resulting file and set a new password. You should be able to do that with Adobe Acrobat or tools like [pdftk](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk)